# Android RSS reader GUI problem

Tags: android

I have an RSS reader which display the titles of a RSS feeds in a list. on clicking the title the main source page of the title should open...
the following code works fine for a small list but if i have a long list which contains feeds from more than one website the application stops and i have to force close it.
can anybody help me to fix it please.

```
@Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Intent viewMessage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse(messages.get(position).getLink().toExternalForm()));
            this.startActivity(viewMessage);
        }
```

Comment: what error do you get in logcat?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 69, size is 3
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(645):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(645):     at org.example.reader.Aggregator.onListItemClick(Aggregator.java:48)
android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321)
android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)

Comment: the line 48 is Uri.parse(messages.get(position).getLink().toExternalForm()));

Comment: Looks like line 48 in onListItemClick in your ListActivity is crashing. Check your position/index as its out of bounds. Do you have header/footer list items?

Comment: Jeez, index of 69? Where you initiate your messages object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, depending on how many pages you're parsing, you'll want to start an asynchronous task.  Basically you'll start a new thread separate from your UI thread so you won't have to force close the application.  Read more about asynchronous tasks here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Also - if you implement error checking you'll be able to continue to run the application if you do get an exception from parsing.